# PHP create unique value compared to values from object

Tags: php, arrays, object, unique

I need to create a unique value for $total, to be different from all other values from received object. It should compare total with order_amount from object, and then if it is the same, it should increase its value by 0.00000001, and then check again through that object to see if it matches again with another order_amount. The end result should be a unique value, with minimal increase compared to the starting $total value. All values are set to have 8 decmal places.

I have tried with the following but it won't get me the result i need. What am i doing wrong?

```
function unique_amount($amount, $rate) {

    $total = round($amount / $rate, 8);
    $other_amounts = some object...;

    foreach($other_amounts as $amount) {
        if ($amount->order_amount == $total) {
            $total = $total + 0.00000001;
        }
    }

    return $total;
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  (php -v).  There are known bugs with PHP and decimals around 5.3 or 5.4.  Just one tip: $total += 0.00000001 is the same as $total = $total + 0.00000001;  Further more, you can "type cast" the $total as float, and at should help with: settype($foo, "float");  You can also set the decimal percision: number_format($number, X, '.', ''); where X is the number of decimals place you expect.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do here. Anyway, this would fail if you have `$other_amounts = [4.00000001,4]` and `$total = 4`. For now, just consider `$other_amounts` as an array of floats.

Comment: PHP is version 7. @vivek_23 The amounts must match precisely, and they all have 8 decimal places. I am trying to create a unique value, not to match the values from object, but to have a minimal increase compared to the original value of $total.

Comment: @user2406735 You didn't get the point. When you find a `match` and do `$total = $total + 0.00000001;` , it is possible that this `new $total` was previously found but just didn't have a match because `$total` was `different initially`.

Comment: @vivek_23 If values match, it should get the new total and compare it again with the same object. I have tried creating it as a function, and then break the foreach to runt the function again with new total, but wasn't able to get the result. Do you understand what i want, and are you able to help? Thanks

Comment: @user2406735 Something like this- `$other_amounts = [4.00000001,4.00000000] and $total = 4.00000000`. The answer to this should be `4.00000002`, but your code will give `4.00000001`. P.S- I am assuming float comparison matches with the latter and not the former value.

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, how can i achieve that?

Comment: @user2406735 How big can be the size of `$other_amounts` array at the maximum?

Comment: It doesn't have a maximum size, it can be 10-50 or more, but not expected to be more.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly why you need that, but I guess that might not be entirely necessary to try a solution. Wait a minute.

Comment: @Rafael I am trying to get a unique amount for some alternative payment, in order for easy detection of amount and distinguishing an order. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe there might be better ways to do that, sir, but why not? :)

Comment: This is the exact way i would need it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't take it as an offense, that's not what I meant. I, for one, need to convince myself quite often not to try to reinvent the wheel. But, for practice, I'm gonna see what I can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

define('EPSILON',0.00000001);
$total = 4.00000000;
$other_amounts = [4.00000001,4.00000000,4.00000002];

sort($other_amounts);

foreach($other_amounts as $each_amount){
    if($total === $each_amount){ // $total === $each_amount->order_amount , incase of objects
        $total += EPSILON;
    }
}

var_dump($total);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
float(4.00000003)
```

You may add an additional `break` if `$total < $each_amount` to make it a bit more efficient.

**UPDATE**

To sort objects in `$other_amounts` based on `amount`, you can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
usort($other_amounts,function($o1,$o2){
    if($o1->order_amount < $o2->order_amount ) return -1;
    else if($o1->order_amount > $o2->order_amount ) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: What if $other_amounts = [1.00000000,4.00000001,4.00000000,4.00000002]; I would still need 4.00000003 but in this case it will start from 1?

Comment: @user2406735 The answer will still be `4.00000003` for `[1.00000000,4.00000001,4.00000000,4.00000002]`. You may run it and check.

Comment: a removal of values bellow $total would possibly work then

Comment: @user2406735 You may have to change `sort()` function a bit since `$other_amounts` is a collection of objects in your case.

Comment: How can i sort object values?

Comment: The $total in if($total === $each_amount) doesn't get updated, it always says as the initial value...This was the isue i originally had. How can this be changed?

Comment: @user2406735 In your case, you have to do `$total === $each_amount->order_amount`

Comment: @user2406735 It takes effort to help you. Please give me an update on whether it worked or didn't work. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After further looking into the direction you pointed, the problem was in the comparison of floats. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2406735 Great! Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the solution I came up with. First I created a function to deliver random objects with random totals so I could work with, unnecessary for you but useful for the sake of this test:

```
function generate_objects()
{
    $outputObjects = [];

    for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $object = new \stdClass();

        $mainValue = random_int(1,9);
        $decimalValue = random_int(1,9);

        $object->order_amount = "{$mainValue}.0000000{$decimalValue}";

        $outputObjects[] = $object;
    }

    return $outputObjects;
}
```

And now for the solution part, first the code, then the explanation:

```
function unique_amount($amount, $rate) {
    $total = number_format(round($amount / $rate, 8), 4);

    $searchTotal = $total;
    if (strpos((string) $searchTotal, '.') !== false) {
        $searchTotal = str_replace('.', '\.', $searchTotal);
    }

    $other_amounts = generate_objects();

    $similarTotals = [];
    foreach($other_amounts as $amount) {
        if (preg_match("/^$searchTotal/", $amount->order_amount)) {
            $similarTotals[] = $amount->order_amount;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($similarTotals)) {
        rsort($similarTotals);

        $total = ($similarTotals[0] + 0.00000001);
    }

    // DEBUG
    //echo '<pre>';
    //$vars = get_defined_vars();
    //unset($vars['other_amounts']);
    //print_r($vars);
    //die;

    return $total;
}

$test = unique_amount(8,1);

echo $test;
```

I decided to use RegEx to find the amounts that starts with the ones I provided. Since in the exercise I provided only integers with 1-9 in the last decimal case, I tracked them and added them to one array `$similarTotals`.

Then I sorted this array, if not empty, descending by the values, got the first item and incremented by 0.00000001.

So, finally, returning either the $total (assuming nothing was found) or the incremented first item in the array.

PS. I did not expect this code to be this big but, well...

You can see the test here: https://3v4l.org/WGThI